# createjs: is it possible to justify text?

Tags: javascript, css, createjs

I'm using CreateJS toolkit for Flash. I get a js file buy when I edit it, I realize "justify" text doesn't work. In Createjs docs I can see only "left", "right" or "center" are recognised. Is there any way to justify it? 
This doesn't work:

```
this.text_2.textAlign = "justify";
```

I've tried inserting css with javascript but it also doesn't work (my html banner stops working at all):

```
this.text_2.style.cssText = "text-align:justify"
this.text_2.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: justify');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Justify is not available as an option in CreateJS

Comment: Thanks beerwin.
But since code is javascript, isn't there any way to add somewhere in the js file a css style for that text?

Comment: You can't apply css to elements drawn inside a canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you use EaselJS. So the short answer is no.
Since createJS is a canvas library, it only support following values: `start`, `end`, `left`, `right`, and `center`.
You can read further details here:

[EaselJS API Doc](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/files/easeljs_display_Text.js.html#l98)

[HTML Canvas Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-textalign)

Comment: Thanks duonglk.
But as code is javascript, isn't there any way to add somewhere in the js file a css style for that text?

Comment: Canvas text does not support CSS. You can use the EaselJS DOMElement class to help position a DIV that contains CSS-justified text though.

Comment: Ok, thanks Lanny. I've read EaselJS DOMElement documentation but I can't find anything about divs. Any examples of what you say? Thanks again!

Comment: Check out the DOMElement example in GitHub: https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/examples/DOMElement.html -- Basically, the DOMElement wraps any HTML element, and lets you position and transform it.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. [It should be](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) (assuming that this.text_2 is a DOM element):

```
this.text_2.style.textAlign = 'justify';
```

But I am not sure if that would fix your problem as I don't know this library.